# Tangency point rotated ellipse and circle.

Tags: calculus

I need to grind an ellipse shape from a round bar with a grinding wheel diameter 400 mm. The round bar and the grinding wheel centers are in the same axis (horizontal). Need to calculate the contact point of the ellipse and the grinding wheel (Center distance between the wheel and the center of the ellipse) in each of the angular rotation position.I know everything on the ellipse, semi-axes a-b,focci distance,ellipse radius at each rotation angle. I the ellipse is rotated 15 degrees the wheel-ellipse contact point is not at the 15 degrees rotation.

**Data ellipse**: a-b axes, circle r, angle of rotation,radius of rotated point. Find distance betw.centers. Both centers in the same axis.
Ellipse semi-axis: 120-80, Circle radius 200,Angle of rotation15 degrees (from 0-360).

Comment: Q. is too terse.

Comment: Please YOU HELP us understanding what you wrote.

Comment: I need to grind an ellipse shape from a round bar with a grinding wheel diameter 400 mm. The round bar and the grinding wheel centers are in the same axis (horizontal). Need to calculate the contact point of the ellipse and the grinding wheel (Center distance between the wheel and the center of the ellipse) in each of the angular rotation position.I know everything on the ellipse, semi-axes a-b,focci distance,ellipse radius at each rotation angle. I the ellipse is rotated 15 degrees the wheel-ellipse contact point is not at the 15 degrees rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Ellipse

$$\begin{cases}x=a\cos\theta,\\y=b\sin\theta.\end{cases}$$

Tangent vector $(-a\sin\theta,b\cos\theta)$, hence circle center

$$\begin{cases}x=a\cos\theta\pm\dfrac{br\cos\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}},\\y=b\sin\theta\pm\dfrac{ar\sin\theta}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\theta+b^2\cos^2\theta}}.\end{cases}$$

Good luck.

Comment: r is the circle radius?

Comment: @RicardoTiburcio: check OP.